# Ошибка в Rider при запуске, во время выполнения сихронизации шаблонов

Tags: c#, rider

Пользуюсь Windows 7x64 Ultimate. Хочу попробовать Jet Brains Rider  но получаю постоянную ошибку при запуске постоянное зависание, причем на всех версиях Rider 2017-2018 Как отключить эту синхронизацию и побороть ошибку при запуске, а также глянув лог с екзепшинами то он пустой ...

[image: Синхронизация]

[image: Ошибка при запуске]

Comment: Поправил название вопроса и картинку, Убрал лишнее приветствие. Если вы все же хотите откатить вопрос, то оставьте безусловно полезные изменения.

Comment: @Kromster - по хоже я уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос.спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно я нашел проблему и она заключается в версиях .NET Framework. Как я понимаю для 2018 (100%) нужна версия мин. .NET 4.6.1, для некоторых обновлений 2017 обновления вероятно от 2017.1.4 нужна тоже уже версия .NET 4.5.7. 
Для версии 2017.1 требуется .NET 4.5.2 (не выше). потому что  у иеня стоит 4.5.2

Comment: Странно что они про это в ошибке и в логах не пишут, но раз это помогает, то отлично! )